# Unix: copy files sequentially

Tags: unix

As far as I remeber, long time ago I've been using such a thing: in total commander I pressed F2 in copy dialoge - added "copy task" into a "Copy queue". And so, all those files have been copied sequentially. Is there any simple tool for such a "sequential" coping?

Edit: I'd want to add "copy tasks" to the queue dynamicly.

Example: I have lots of heavy files. I understand what I want to copy file A. While file A is coping, I understand that I also must copy file B to somewhere, but I need to start coping it right after A is already copied.

Comment: What queue? Why don't you just use `cp`?

Comment: So, what you are trying to avoid is copying more than one file at the same time?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And an ability to change this sequence dynamicly. I apologize for being unable to express what I want today enving.

Comment: To do two tasks after each other use `;`, `&&` or `||`.  E,g  'task1 ; task2' will run task1, and then task2. Both tasks could by copy commands.   ( && and || are conditionals.  `task1 && task2` means run task1, if succesful (no error condition) then run task2, else skip task2.  || or the reverse, run only on error. )

Comment: Example:  `cp *.mp3 /music backup ; cp *.divX /movie_backup` would run the two copy command sequentially after each other.

Comment: See my updated answer for a convoluted way of doing what you want.

Comment: Do you need a terminal solution or is a Total Commander clone enough for you? "krusader" from KDE contains the copy queue feature as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, that is the default behavior of the copy command (`cp`):

- Copy many files:

  ```
  cp *txt *jpg destination_dir
  ```

Here are some examples of more complex operations:

1. Copy all files read from a list (**assuming sane file names, no spaces or weird characters**):

   ```
   while read n; do cp $n destination_dir < file_list.txt
   ```
2. As above but works for file names with spaces or strange characters:

   ```
   while IFS= read -r n; do cp "$n" destination_dir < file_list.txt
   ```
3. Find all files matching a pattern and copy them:

   ```
   find . -name "*data*" -exec cp {} destination_dir \;
   ```
4. As above but works with weird file names:

   ```
   find . -print0 -name "*data*" | xargs -0 cp -t destination_dir \;
   ```

---

I still don't understand *why* you would want to do this but OK. To add a copy operation to be executed after the current one has ended, you could do this:

1. Create a list of the files you want to copy. Since you start with one file, the list will contain just one file name:

   ```
   echo "fileA" > list.txt
   ```
2. Start copying the file by reading the list (as before, this assumes **sane** file names, use example 2 from the list above if your file name can contain spaces or strange, non alphanumeric  characters):

   ```
   while read n; do cp -v $n destination_dir < file_list.txt
   ```
3. Find the next file you want to copy and add it to the list:

   ```
   echo "fileB" >> list.txt
   ```

As long as you do step 3 before the copying has finished, the next file will be copied as soon as the first one is done.

I just don't understand why you don't simply launch many independent `cp` commands instead. You are complicating things with no reason as far as I can tell.

Comment: I know, thank you. I'd want to add "copy tasks" to the queue dynamicly.

Comment: You mean you _need_ a solution for total commander?

Comment: I need something, that works under unix just like "TC copy queue" did under windows.

Comment: I figured that out but I have never used "TC copy queue". Could you please explain _why_ you need to start copying fileB _only after_ fileA has finished? Otherwise you can just launch N `cp` commands in parallel.